# Big Double in Scala templates and Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, twirl

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.6 and Scala

When I'm trying to display input with big Double i.e. 55 000 000 it displays in input 5.5E7

```
@inputText(field("price"), '_label -> "Price")

<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="5.5E7">
```

How can I change default formatting or somehow display it properly?

Comment: Please see my answer below. By the way if you could provide more details about how you define `field` (is it a form?) I might be able to edit the answer to give more relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is due to the `toString` representation of the `Double` value.

For instance

```
scala> val a: Double = 55000000
a: Double = 5.5E7

scala> a.toString
res8: String = 5.5E7
```

**`Double` type**

According to [Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/), the[`Double`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Double) type is a 64-bit floating point number equivalent to Java's `double` primitive type.

Now if `Double` is what you really need, you should format it properly, otherwise you can use [`Long`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Long) type.

**Formating**

You can refer to [String Interpolation section](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) in Scala docs for more info on formatting, but briefly, you can achieve what you want with

```
"%1.0f" format a
```

which gives you `55000000` as result.

**Play helpers**

I would say you should customize this where you define your `Form` (or your `Field` if you don't have any `Form`) and not in the template file.

What you need to change is the `format` defined in `play.api.data.Mapping` class :

```
/**
 * The Format expected for this field, if it exists.
 */
val format: Option[(String, Seq[Any])] = None
```

in case of defining a `Form`, or `format` passed to `Field` case class in case of using a `Field` directly:

```
/**
 * @param format the format expected for this field
 */
case class Field(private val form: Form[_], name: String, constraints: Seq[(String, Seq[Any])], format: Option[(String, Seq[Any])], errors: Seq[FormError], value: Option[String])
```